# Need help reading hand-written character from comic

Tags: meaning, katakana, manga, handwriting

[image: comic line image]

Yeah, I know; everyone's favorite type of question.  I just need help with making the character out.

> はははっ…[sweatdrop] [？]コミにはしったぞえ。

I can't read the character before コミ.

Answer (score 3):

What you read as コ is actually a small ュ, so シュミにはしった.

The precise meaning has to be determined from context, but はしった is to be understood in the figurative sense (e.g. someone "fooling around" / having fun instead of acting responsibly).

Comment: `はしった` is from `走る`? On the dictionary I found only that, but I can't find that meaning listed on the dictionaries I checked; if so, it's something gergal?

Comment: @Mauro Yes, it's from 走る. I don't think this meaning is necessarily noted in the dictionary. If you say "someone is hiding from his responsibilities", you don't mean that they're hiding in a closet or behind a tree. So here, too, 趣味に走った literally means "running to his hobby/hobbies", but it doesn't mean they're literally running to basketball training or to the movies...